# PHP CURLOPT_INTERFACE is returning 0 byte files

Tags: php, curl

Alright so in a script I have, I want to communicate with another server and retrieve a file from the server. Normally I would not have any cURL option specifying what IP address (interface) to use but the server will only let me download if it knows the connection established is between 188.138.110.125 (my IP address) and the server. So I edited my script to look like this:

```
<?php

$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

$cookie_file = './sessions/cookie.txt';

// exit if the script is called directly
if ( empty($url) )
    die();

$url = "http://www.example.com/file.zip";

// checking if the login session is valid
$logged_in = 0;

if ( file_exists($cookie_file) )
{
    $cookie = file_get_contents($cookie_file);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.example.com/testfile.zip&'.$cookie_file,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '188.138.110.125',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $logged_in = !preg_match('~ERROR~', $content);
}

// logging in and storing the cookie
if ( !$logged_in )
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/login.php?login='.urlencode($user).'&password='.urlencode($pass).'&withcookie=1',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '188.138.110.125',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match('~cookie=([0-9A-F]+)~', $content, $match);

    if ( empty($match[1]) )
        die('Error: login failed');

    $cookie = "enc={$match[1]}";

    file_put_contents($cookie_file, $cookie);
}

//----------------------- THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM HAPPENS ---------------------------
// checking if the direct link to the file is available
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '188.138.110.125',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~Location: ([^\s]+)~', $content, $match);

// if the direct link to the file was not found
if ( empty($match[1]) )
    // display any other errors
    if ( preg_match('~(ERROR: [^\n]+)~', $content, $match) )
        die("Error {$match[1]}");
    else
        die('Error: undefined error (1)');

$direct_link = $match[1];

// extracting filename
$pieces = explode('/', $direct_link);
$filename = end($pieces);

// extrating the size of the file
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $direct_link,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '188.138.110.125',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~Content-Length: (\d+)~', $content, $match);
$filesize = $match[1];

// setting headers for the user
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: filename=$filename");
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

// printing the file
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $direct_link,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '188.138.110.125',
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookie
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

But now it when it downloads the file, it downloads a file that is 0 bytes. The file name is accurate and so is the extension of the file, it just has no size. This problem only started when I added CURLOPT_INTERFACE => '188.138.110.125', into the script. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

NOTE: If I keep on trying to download, at a completely random time it will actually find the right file size, but if I do it again I get no luck.

Comment: Did you see this comment? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#75693

Comment: Yup, but I added the useragent and still no luck. Also it was always working without a useragent.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense... can you please provide more details? How's EXACTLY your current code?

Comment: Okay I threw in the whole script but I am pretty sure the problem still lies in the area I told you earlier.

Comment: `CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.example.com/testfile.zip&'.$cookie_file,` should it be `CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.example.com/testfile.zip&'.$cookie,` or something similar?

Comment: No because I can verify that the communication between my site and the file site is fine when I output the cURL executions. 

Also, the IP that is in the interface option is a second IP I bought for my server.

Comment: Still no idea? I really need help on this one

Comment: Sorry pal, I really don't know what's causing the issue.